# Factor group of a $p$-group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, p-groups, group-presentation

I asked this question a few days ago in [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/250192/generalization-of-a-property-of-an-extraspecial-p-group)
but got no answer, so I try here. Any hint will be appreciated.

Let $$M(p^3)=\langle a, b\mid a^{p^2}=b^p=1,  a^b=a^{p+1}\rangle$$  and 
$$G=\langle a, b\mid a^{p^n}=b^{p^m}=1,  a^b=a^{p^{n-m}+1}\rangle.$$
 Does there exist a normal subgroup $N$ of $G$ such that $G/N\cong M(p^3)$?
($p$ is an odd prime and $n>m\geq 1$).

Comment: A [good reference](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/694445/8581).

Comment: I haven't worked it out in detail, but I think the answer is yes if and only if $n-m=1$. If $n-m > 1$ then all quotients of order $p^3$ are abelian.