# Writing a quotient group as a product of cyclic groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups, quotient-group, direct-product

Let $G = \mathbb{Z}_{12} \times \mathbb{Z}_{12}$, and let $a$ be a generator of $\mathbb{Z}_{12}$.

Consider the subgroup $H$ generated by $(a^4, a^6)$. I need to write $G/H$ as a product of cyclic groups each of which has order equal to a power of some prime.

My work

Here $|H| =6$, so by Lagrange's theorem we have $|G/H|=\dfrac{144}{6}=24=8\times 3 = 2^3 \times 3$.

Can I say that $G/H \cong \mathbb{Z}_8 \times \mathbb{Z}_3$?

Comment: Would you consider $\mathbb Z_4 \times \mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_3$ as a possibility? What about $\mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_3$?

Comment: @LeeMosher, should I calculate the elements of $G/H$ to determine which one is the case?

Comment: What you are *asked* to do is to construct an isomorphism from $G/H$ to a group as asked.

Comment: So, not just to ***identify*** which one (by whatever means, perhaps your idea of a calculation would be fine), but then, once you have identified the correct group, to ***write $G/H$ as*** that group, which formally means to construct an isomorphism.

Comment: @LeeMosher, is there elegent way to construct this isomorphism and prove it? Any hint or theorem to apply?

Comment: Note that the square of the generator of $H$ is $(a^8,1)$.  Hence it contains its square, which is $(a^4,1)$. Thus, $H$ is also generated by $(a^4,1)$ and $(1,a^6)$. That makes computing $G/H$ much simpler. Your argument is invalid /incomplete because the group you list is not the only abelian group of that order.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin, So, the required map $\phi: G \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_8$ defined by  $\phi(a,a)=(a^3,a^2)$. Then I only need to show that $\phi$ is surjective homo then by first isomorphism theorem, we have $G/H$ and $\mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_8$ are isomorphic, right?

Comment: $(a,a)$ does not generate $G$. You have not defined a morphism yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By [this standard result](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2376694/104041), a presentation for $G$ is

$$\langle x,y\mid x^{12}, y^{12}, xy=yx\rangle.$$

The element that generates $H$ corresponds to $x^4y^6$, so that, by definition of a presentation, we have

$$G/H\cong\langle x,y\mid x^{12}, y^{12}, xy=yx, x^4y^6\rangle.$$

Now we can perform Tietze transformations:

$$\begin{align}
G/H&\cong\langle x,y\mid x^{12}, y^{12}, xy=yx, x^4=y^{-6}=y^6\rangle\\
&\cong \langle x,y\mid x^{12}, (y^6)^2, xy=yx, x^4=y^6\rangle\\
&\cong\langle x,y\mid x^{12}, (x^4)^2, xy=yx, x^4=y^6\rangle\\
&\cong\langle x,y\mid x^{\gcd(12,8)}=x^4=e, y^6=x^4, xy=yx\rangle\\
&\cong\langle x,y\mid x^4, y^6, xy=yx\rangle\\
&\cong\Bbb Z_4\times\Bbb Z_6\\
&\cong \Bbb Z_{12}\times\Bbb Z_2,
\end{align}$$

where the final isomorphism is because $\Bbb Z_{12}\cong\Bbb Z_4\times\Bbb Z_3$ while $\Bbb Z_6\cong\Bbb Z_3\times \Bbb Z_2$.

Comment: Thank youf or your answer, but I couldn't understand what you mean by the last condition in the presentation of $G/H$, in particular, $x^4 y^6$.

Comment: Think of $x=(a,0)$ and $y=(0,b)$, @Adam_math. Then $x^4y^6=(a^4,b^6)$. For any group $L\cong\langle X\mid R\rangle$ for sets of generators $X$ and relations $R$, if $M=\langle\langle S\rangle\rangle$ is the normal subgroup generated by a set of relations $S$, then $$L/M\cong\langle X\mid R\cup S\rangle.$$

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/694416/104041) might help, @Adam_math.

Comment: The last condition, @Adam_math, means $$x^4y^6=e.$$

Comment: thank you very much for the clarification. How do you know that the subgroup $H$ is normal? is that because it is cyclic?

Comment: can we write the final isomorphism in terms of cyclic groups whose orders are powers of some primes?

Comment: Every subgroup of an abelian group is normal, @Adam_math. And yes: $$G/H\cong \Bbb Z_4\times \Bbb Z_3\times\Bbb Z_2.$$